# Azure AD WebAPI return Not Authorization even with request passes an access token from Angular client

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

I have an angular client which was able to authenticate and received a token from Azure AD. I added the token to the header and called the WebAPI. I constantly get the following message

"Authorization has been denied for this request."

I get this error with the Angular and Google Postman.

From the angular, I added the token to the header request as the following

```
this.http.get<T>(endpointUrl, this.getHeaderWithToken());
```

from the getHeaderWithToken call, I do see the token is added to the header

```
let token = this.authService.getAccessToken();
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
```

I also used Postman, Clicked on Authorization tab, pasted the token in the Token field.

Both returned a failed message.

On the webAPI code

I created a startup file inside the App_Start folder, I verified that the following code is called

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var azureADBearerAuthOptions = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"]
        };

        azureADBearerAuthOptions.TokenValidationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"]
            };

        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(azureADBearerAuthOptions);
    }
```

It is registered on Azure AD.

This test should work with Google Postman, right?

I am trying to call this test message to see if my request is working

```
    [Route("test")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize] 
    public string Test()
    {
            return "Success";

    }
```

The request does break on the constructor but does not allow to call this test method. Yes, it works without the [Authorize].

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you inspect the angular token (on https://jwt.ms for example), is the claim `aud` one of the ones inside `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the middleware to validate the token, you need to make sure that you have correctly configured the `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions.Audience` or `TokenValidationParameters.AllowedAudience`(s) which would be compared with the **`aud`** property from the incoming **`JWT`** token. You could press F12 when browsing your app and trace the Network or use Fiddler to capture your bearer token, then use **`https://jwt.io/`** to decode your token.

Moreover, if you use the built-in Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service for your backend web app, you need to correctly configure the Client ID or ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES for AD [authentication under the Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) blade of your app service app.

Details you could follow the tutorials [Azure AD AngularJS getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular) and [Integrating Azure AD into an AngularJS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp/) single page app to narrow this issue.

Hope it helps.